# Dynamic Loading on Flask Site with Unique URL

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

I am building a Flask site that dynamically loads some information like the time but I'm running into some issue with AJAX with jQuery.

Following the example on the flask site https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/jquery/

I want to change it to a dynamic URL based on the users **unique ID** instead of a static one.

Python File:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/_add_numbers/<UNIQUEID>')
def add_numbers():
    a = request.args.get('a', 0, type=int)
    b = request.args.get('b', 0, type=int)
    return jsonify(result=a + b)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The HTML

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  $(function() {
    $('a#calculate').bind('click', function() {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_add_numbers/UNIQUEID', {
        a: $('input[name="a"]').val(),
        b: $('input[name="b"]').val()
      }, function(data) {
        $("#result").text(data.result);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
<h1>jQuery Example</h1>
<p><input type=text size=5 name=a> +
   <input type=text size=5 name=b> =
   <span id=result>?</span>
<p><a href=# id=calculate>calculate server side</a>
```

I cannot figure out how to put a unique ID into the HTML.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to do this. I would recommend simply adding the user's id into the template context, with `render_template("index.html", user_id=current_user.id)` (make sure you import `current_user` from flask. This will return a user id if the user is logged in, and `None` if not. Then you can do the following:

```js
$(function() {
    $("a#calculate").bind("click", function() {
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/_add_numbers/{{ user_id }}",
       etc etc: your code goes here
       )}
    )}
```

That should do it.

Alternatively you could actually use the value of `current_user.id` (if you feel you understand it) in the template, as this is implicitly passed down with Jinja anyway. o substitute `{{ user_id }}` with `{{ current_user.id }}.

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely helpful!  My unique ID is actually from my flask_sqlalchemy database.  I've been passing it to each route in the form of a URL so events/7 for instance.  Could I use this database unique value in place of 'current_user.id' ?

Comment: Yes, you can pass any value to the template. In this case it’d  be the value of the id of who made the request